# RegularExpression String replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have html code as a string variable

like a = "<span> Spain will win ....... </span>"

and I want to heightlight "spa" in the String.

I have to use RegExp, How should I write the pattern that it ignores the "spa" on span tag, but highlight in Spain.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, so you're a bit limited, but this should work:

```
\bSpa(?!n[^>]*>)
```

**Explanation:**

`\b`: Assert that the match starts at a word boundary.

`Spa`: Match `Spa`.

`(?!...)`: Assert that it is impossible to match the following:

`n`: An `n`, followed by...

`[^>]*`: zero or more non-`>` characters, followed by...

`>`: a `>`.

Comment: @Gert G: [quote]and I want to heightlight "spa" in the String.[/quote]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var s = "<span> Spain will win ....... </span>Spaniel";
s.replace(/(spa(?!n[^>]*>))/ig,'<span class="highlight">\$1</span>')
```

Comment: @Gert G: Yes I tried! I didn't highlight Spain, but that wasn't asked for, it should highlight only the "spa" of "spain", but not the "spa" from "<span>". the resulting string:
"<span> <span class="highlight">Spa</span>in will win ....... </span><span class="highlight">Spa</span>niel"